# In MISRA C++ 2008, anyone knows the specialized notion Cvalue expression occured in the rule 5-0-3?

Tags: c++, misra

From the concept of the Cvalue, I realized that

> *"An expression that should not undergo further conversions, either implicitly or explicitly, is called a cvalue expression."*

But with the example presented by this rule.

```
s32 = static_cast < int32_t > ( s8 ) + s8; // Example 2 - Compliant
s32 = s32 + s8; // Example 3 - Compliant
```

Obviously, the right addition expressions occur implicitly and explicitly conversions here. And this rule mark them as compliant. I think it is conflicted with the notion cvalue.

Comment: Can you explain or include a link to the definition of "cvalue" for those of us who aren't familiar with MISRA?

Comment: Yeap, just like what I have said, the defintion of "cvalue" is `An expression that should not undergo further conversions, either implicitly or explicitly, is called a cvalue expression.`[misra 2008 compliance](https://bpb.opendns.com/a/www.ldra.com/attachments/article/74/MISRA-CPP_2008_COMPLIANCE.pdf?reg=short)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end of page 57, MISRA Cpp 2008:

> Similar, unless listed below:
>
> - . . .
> - The other unlisted expressions are not *cvalues* and have the *underlying type* of the operation.

Reading the long list after that paragraph, nothing can be applied to `s8`.

Then, `s8` is not *cvalues*, it has the underlying type of the operation, in your example, its underlying type is `int32_t`. The promotion to `int32_t` doesn't violate the rule.

---

The whole point of 5-0-3 is it wants to ensure all operations are performed in the same underlying type.

```
int32_t s32;
int8_t s8;
s32 = static_cast < int32_t > ( s8 ) + s8; // Example 2 - Compliant
s32 = s32 + s8; // Example 3 - Compliant
```

In those above examples, the `+` is performed with the underlying type of `int32_t` (by now, most of `int` is `int32_t` or `int16_t`), return the underlying type of `int32_t`, then assign to an `int32_t` variable, thus compliant with MISRA Cpp.

In this example:

```
int32_t s32;
int8_t s8;
s32 = s8 + s8;
```

It doesn't compliance because the additive operator is performed with the type of `int`, the result will be converted to `int32_t` which is not necessary the same with `int`, thus not-compliance.

Comment: Actually in C++ `signed char x=127, y=127; int z=x+y;` is perfectly defined to result in `z` being 254 in any implementation.

Comment: I agree with you viewpoint. The same quote with you:In the end of page 57, MISRA Cpp 2008:` Binary expressions are not cvalues and their underlying type is the result of applying the underlying type conversions.` Here it says Binary expressions are not cvalues, whether this is conflicted with the `s32 = static_cast < int32_t > ( s8 ) + s8; // Example 2 - Compliant`. <br> And if I chang the code like this:`s32 = (int32_t)(s8 + s8);` Should it be non-compliant.

Comment: It's listed under additive section later

Comment: So do you consider that ` s32 = static_cast < int32_t > ( s8 ) + s8`,should be a cvalue expression belong to assignment operators "=" not an additive operators"+".

Comment: cvalue by whatever constraint